# Google map dentro do modal Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Estou querendo incorporar o google maps dentro do modal bootstrap. Através de algumas buscas, esbarrei com o código abaixo, porém o mapa não aparece:

http://www.bootply.com/106707

Comment: Nesse link que você passou, o mapa está aparecendo normalmente. Você não consegue visualizar o mapa? Teste em outro browser, ou outro PC, ou outra Rede/Internet.

Comment: Já fiz isso, mas infelizmente o mapa não aparece. Estou usando o bootstrap v3.3.6

Comment: Se tiver outro modelo, não tem problema...esse foi apenas um dos, que encontrei...

Comment: Veja essa: http://jsfiddle.net/wgur1z7n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que para usar o google maps você tem de usar uma key que o google fornece para utilizar a API para que tenha a permissão do Google. Se informe melhor aqui: https://developers.google.com/maps/

Comment: Olá Rafael. Na verdade o mapa seria apenas a localização do endereço dos clientes do meu cliente. O projeto terá uma página onde trará os clientes dele e ao lado de cada descrição, teria um link que abriria um modal com o mapa do endereço de cada um dentro. Nesse caso, teria que ter uma API também?

Comment: Jose Marcos, a API é bem simples de usar, é tudo com javascript, eu acredito que para vc fazer isso você teria que pegar e checar no banco o endereço de cada um para poder seta as coordenadas, vc seta no javascript as coordenadas e fica marcado no mapa. Sim teria a API, pode relaxar, é fácil de se trabalhar com ela, o mais difícil vai ser saber as coordenadas de cada cliente do seu cliente.